# jQuery show hide un-orderd list depending on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show the "ul" when select yes from dropdown is selected. It working fine when clicking on it. But i want it on page load if the option 'Yes' is already selected or hide when option 'No' is already selected.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Limit').on('change', function() {
          if ( this.value == 'true')
          {
            $("#first-piller").show();
          }
          else
          {
            $("#first-piller").hide();
          }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Limit">
        <option value="true" selected>Yes</option>
        <option value="false">No</option>
        </select>
        
         <!-- Show hide depending selection -->

        <ul id="first-piller">
        <li>
        <div class="left col-sm-6  col-xs-6 text-left left-indent" id="overview" >
        <p><b>First Piller</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="right col-sm-6  col-xs-6" class="pillers">
        <select><option value="1">4 or more</option>
            <option value="2" >0 - 3 </option>
            <option value="3" >0 or more</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: just don't use only the change event but at document ready if $('#Limit').val()==true or $('#Limit option:selected').val()==true after show hide..you must write the same code that you have writte in change event using $('#Limit').val(), you need of two event on on change and one on document ready from the value of the selected.

Answer (score 2):

When your DOM is ready, and after the `change` event is bound, you can trigger it manually:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // your rest of the code

  $('#Limit').change();
});
```

This will trigger the change event which will eventually execute the code of the event handler.

Comment: I want to detect if it is switched on already using Jquery as I'm handling which should be selected (yes or no) from the PHP when rendering the page. Can you let me know how to apply in this regards?

Comment: @Zain -- The code I posted will automatically do it for you. It will check its value, and then hide/show the `ul` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and call it on both situations

```
function FirstPiller(sender)
{
if ( sender.val() == 'true')
  {
    $("#first-piller").show();
  }
  else
  {
    $("#first-piller").hide();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    FirstPiller($('#Limit'));
    console.log("Calling");
});

$('#Limit').on('change', function() {
  FirstPiller($(this));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The smart thing to do in this case would be to extract the logic into it's own function (i.e. *togglePillar*). That way you can fire it on document load and also pass it in as a callback in your `change` event handler:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $limit = $('#Limit');
  var $firstPillar = $("#first-piller");
  
  togglePillar();
  
  $limit.on('change', togglePillar);

  function togglePillar() {
    if ($limit.val() == 'true') {
      $firstPillar.show();
    } else {
      $firstPillar.hide();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Limit">
    <option value="true" selected>Yes</option>
    <option value="false">No</option>
    </select>

<!-- Show hide depending selection -->

<ul id="first-piller">
  <li>
    <div class="left col-sm-6  col-xs-6 text-left left-indent" id="overview">
      <p><b>First Piller</b></p>
    </div>
    <div class="right col-sm-6  col-xs-6" class="pillers">
      <select><option value="1">4 or more</option>
        <option value="2" >0 - 3 </option>
        <option value="3" >0 or more</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use .ready function

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 // Code you want to run at the start
})
```

Comment: Really i don't understand who puts -1, you said the right thing and people put -1 it's absurd....Reading comments just create a function write millions of line of code instead it's so simple $(document).ready(function(){if ($('#Limit').val()=='true'){}})